# How to implement encryption and decryption in vb.net core

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a desktop application and I want to achieve more security, I have module for login and User for creating users and showing their details

I want to get the password encrypted and once the user try to login it will decrypt in order to read in my system.

Here is how I retrieve my users

```
 Private Function GetUsers(ByVal userid As String) As DataTable
        Dim dtUserid As New DataTable()

        ' Query to fetch the data from the database
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM tblemployee WHERE userid = @userid ORDER by id "

        Using command As New SqlCommand(query, LoginForm.Sqlconnection)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid)
            Try
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                dtUserid.Load(reader)

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message, "MIS DEPARTMENT", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End Using

        Return dtUserid
    End Function
```

Here is how I input it in my Textbox

```
 Dim userid As String = txtEmpno.Text
            Dim dtUsers As DataTable = GetUsers(userid)

            If dtUsers.Rows.Count > 0 Then

                bAdd = False
                Me.txtEmpname.Text = dtUsers.Rows(0)("username")
                Me.txtPassword.Text = dtUsers.Rows(0)("password")
                Me.txtConfirm.Text = dtUsers.Rows(0)("password")

                Me.chkAdmin.Checked = dtUsers.Rows(0)("admin")
                Me.chkFast.Checked = dtUsers.Rows(0)("allowgetdata")
                Me.chkEdit.Checked = dtUsers.Rows(0)("allowedit")
                Me.chktugboat.Checked = dtUsers.Rows(0)("allowtugboat")
                Me.chkUsers.Checked = dtUsers.Rows(0)("allowuserfile")
                Me.chkReport.Checked = dtUsers.Rows(0)("allowreport")
```

Comment: The "proper" way to handle passwords is with hashing, not encryption. An encrypted password could be recovered, whereas a hashed password basically can't be recovered from the hashed value. The idea is that you hash the password provided when the user registers and store the result, then you hash the password provided when they login and compare the two hashed values. You should look into that specifically and do your best to implement it, then post a specific question if you encounter a specific issue. Note that Microsoft Identity handles this and more.